# Spring Boot tests fail for missing javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring-boot, spock

I have a springboot 1.5.9 using Spock for my integration tests.  These tests all worked before with SpringBoot 1.3.5 but after upgrading Spring and Spock, I get the following when I run

> gradle clean build test

Error on each integration test:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
```

My dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
dependencies {
    querydslapt group: 'com.mysema.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '2.8.0', classifier: 'apt-one-jar', transitive: false

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.0.M1")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.0.M1")
compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE')
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.5.0')

compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.4.Final")
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.4.Final")
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")
compile("org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7")
compile('javax.mail:mail:1.4.1')
compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support")

compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")
compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.3")
compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1")
compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1')
compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
testCompile(group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.1-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }

testCompile(group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '1.1-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spock-core'
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-beans'
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-test'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")
testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7+')
testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

And all my spock tests use this as their base:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MainClass)
@WebAppConfiguration()
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class BaseSpecification extends Specification {

}
```

And here is the main class:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext mc = SpringApplication.run( MainClass.class, args );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For Spring based test, we need the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` so application context is created.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MainClass.class)
@WebAppConfiguration  
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class BaseSpecification extends Specification {

}
```

and also add

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

Comment: You don't need to add `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` spock-spring has direct support for spring tests.